# How to deal with unknown distribution?

Tags: distributions, game-theory

I have a game with two players. Player 1's type is publicly known, while player 2's type is unknown (privately known to him) and distributed, say, from 0 to 1. Both players play their payoff maximizing strategies. Need to find players' equilibrium strategies.
I'm able to solve the game when player 2's type distribution is known. Then player 1's equilibrium strategy is some sort of a weighted sum of best-responses to each possible player 2 type realization. And player 2's equilibrium strategy is a best-response to player 1's equilibrium strategy.
The problem is what to do if player 2's type distribution is unknown. The only thing I know is that player 2's type lies within a known interval [a,b].

Any suggestion on how to approach this?

Comment: If its about keeping score of losses and wins I guess you just make an educated guess and go along with a $\beta$-distribution (e.g. batting example in baseball).

Comment: β-distribution is a good point. I did not know about it before. My game is played only once, so I cannot adjust parameters for β after each play as in the baseball example. What could be the initial parameters?